# Simple question regarding the definition of commuting coordinates

Tags: geometry

What does it mean when coordinates commute? I am having a very difficult time finding a formal definition of this. If context is needed, say it is in reference to it in supergeometry (I am reading intro stuff on it and can't go very far because I can't find a definition of this). There is also a concept of anti-commuting coordinates. I can't tell if there is some formal definition for this or this is supposed to mean something simple. When I search online most references point to commuting operators in quantum (physics) theories, are these related? Could somebody post some rather concrete examples as well please? Thanks for your consideration! -JS

Comment: Might make it easier for us to answer, if you would quote, in full, an example where it says some coordinates commute (or anti-commute).

Comment: "From the point of view of noncommutative geometry, the supergeometry is a very mild special case of noncommutativity in geometry: some coordinates commute, some anticommute."